# socketIO-client-nexus 0.7.6 - StopIteration error

Tags: python-socketio

```
from socketIO_client_nexus import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

try:
    socket = SocketIO('https://myURL/myendpoint', verify=False, wait_for_connection=False)
    socket.wait()
except ConnectionError:
    print('The server is down. Try again later.')
```

When I run the above code, I get the below stack trace.

[image]

This is a quite known issue. People who faced this issue said that it happened because the socket server that they were trying to connect to was built on socketio 2.x.
However, **socketIO-client-nexus 0.7.6** seems to have reportedly solved their problems.
However, I'm still facing the same issue. Don't know what's wrong.
The server that I'm trying to connect to is built on **socketio 2.0.1**

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working. Reference https://pypi.org/project/socketIO-client-nexus/
Here's the working code.

```
from socketIO_client_nexus import SocketIO, BaseNamespace
class ChatNamespace(BaseNamespace):

    def custom_response(self, *args):
        print('on_custom_response', args)


    socketIO = SocketIO('https://myIP', verify=False)
    chat_namespace = socketIO.define(ChatNamespace, '/mynamespace')
    socketIO.wait()
```